# how an action is assigned to the createoperation in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, rbac

I am a newbie and i just read about creating operation for defining the authorization rules...there was a code in the book which is as follows

```
# protected/controllers/SiteController.php::actionSetup()
$auth = Yii::app()->authManager;
$auth->createOperation('createPage',"create a new page");
$auth->createOperation('updatePage',"update a page");
```

The first argument is the identifier that specifies the operation uniquely...second is the description of the operation....
`NOW my QUESTION is` 
 where is the **ACTION** attached to the **operation**..it just consists of the name and the description...?? Even if i assign this operation to a user....how will the rule identify that which action has been assigned to him???

Answer (score 0):

See nice tutorial here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/65/how-to-setup-rbac-with-a-php-file/

You have two main points:

1. In accessRules() method
2. In concrete action, where you just call something like `if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('createPost'))`

Also as a good demo/tutorial with sources you can try this: https://github.com/thyseus/yii-user-management/blob/master/user/docs/install_tutorial.txt